# Download salesforce logs with MavensMate

Tags: debugging, mavensmate, sublime, atom

I'm working with MavensMate and i need to know if there is any way to download the logs that are generated on salesforce. I tried clicking on Start Debugging and it generates the log on salesforce and the user appears as logging enabled, but i don't see the option to download the logs.

Is there any way to do this?

I've tried with atom and sublime with no luck.

Comment: I've tried to setup the mm_workspace variable but it generates MavensMate logs. What i need is to download salesforce logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can see where your logs are stored in your settings/workspace [image]

Comment: Hi,I have the settings setup correctly but in that folder i've no logs :(